# Is it possible to take a type as an argument in a function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function for a database class that is basically just a wrapper around a hash_map of objects (say shapes) indexed by ID numbers that will look up an ID and cast it to the appropriate pointer type.

e.g. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Circle* shapeToLookup = NULL;
int idNum = 12;
database.lookup(idNum, circleToLookup);
if(circleToLookup != NULL)
{
    // Do stuff with the circle.
}
```

and have the database know the type of its argument. Is there a way to do this without either overloading the function (`lookup(int, Circle*)`, `lookup(int, Rect*)`, ad nauseum)? Can you declare a function like `lookup(int, Shape*)` and have it know which type it's given?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, this is really a database question. You also don't say what DB. I would look into the SQL keyword "LIKE."

Comment: How are you planning on passing the type information to the database? (or should I say, how will the database receive it?)

Comment: If you want the database to *do something* with this information, then you will have to write some circle-specific code, some rectangle-specific code, and so on ad nauseam. The question is *where* you want to put this code. Can you tell us what you want the database to do?

Comment: @JustBoo - I just edited to clarify; it's just a hash_map wrapper.
@James Curran - Ideally I'd like the database to know the type of it's argument by the pointer it's given. With a prototype like `lookup(int, Shape*)`, will it always cast the provided object to a `Shape*` or will it be able to know what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a template.

Edit: new implementation based on the extra information. If `mymap` is a `std::map<int, Shape*>`:

```
template <typename T>
void lookup(int idNum, T* &ptr) {
    auto it = mymap.find(idNum);
    if (it == mymap.end()) {
        ptr = 0;
    } else {
        ptr = dynamic_cast<T*>(*it); // Shape must have a virtual member function
    }
}
```

Or you might prefer:

```
template <typename T>
T* lookup(int idNum) {
    auto it = mymap.find(idNum);
    if (it == mymap.end()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(*it);
}
```

Then call it like `Circle *circle = database.lookup<Circle>(123);`

Obviously polymorphic containers are a whole heap of fun in themselves, but I'll assume you have that sorted. There may well be a `shared_ptr` in there somewhere that I've left out.

Old implementation when I thought the DB might store copies of POD:

```
template <typename T>
void lookup(int idNum, T* &ptr) {
    void *theresult = // something based on idNum

    // some check needed here that theresult really is the right type.
    // how you do this depends on the database, but suppose that
    // the database gives us some integer "type" which indicates the type
    if (type != type_constant<T>::value) {
        ptr = 0;
    } else {
        ptr = static_cast<T*>(theresult);
    }
}
```

type_constant is an example of "type traits", you implement it like:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_constant {};

template <>
struct type_constant<Circle> {
    static const int value = 1;
};

template <>
struct type_constant<Rectangle> {
    static const int value = 2;
};

// etc...
```

Comment: Should we not be using dynamic_cast<> to cast towards children types. (ie from Shape* to Circle*)?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know that this database actually returns - if it's a `Shape*` whose referand is a subclass, and if `Shape*` has any virtual member functions, then yes. If the database itself isn't object-based, or then someone somewhere has to do something based on a record that indicates type. I can't tell from the question whether `Shape*` is an actual base class, or just something that the questioner mentioned thinking it might be part of the solution.

Comment: I didn't know about `type_constant`, and I'll likely just look at doing the `dynamic_cast` as Martin mentioned. Bit of a facepalm for not thinking templates right away.

Comment: `type_constant` is just one possibility, I'm imagining that your data is stored as a bytewise copy of some POD, plus a value to indicate type. If your data is stored with proper class-aware serialisation, and a deserialiser that acts as a factory, then by all means `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <T>
Database::lookup(int idNum, T TobjectToLookup)
{
    // inside here, T is the type of the object passed in/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained how to pass a type to a function (by using function templates). I'd like to give another point of view:

It might be even better to introduce a new virtual function on `Shape` and then move the `Do stuff with the Circle` part into the reimplementation of that virtual function in the `Cricle` class.

That way, you remove the need to know the type. You just fetch a `Shape` object from your database and then call a `doStuff()` function - and it does the right thing depending on the actual type of the `Shape`. A good use case for a virtual function. :-)

Of course, this might be more or less simple, depending on what `Do stuff` actually does.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a major refactor job on legacy code where the "shapes" are all heavily dependent on each other, so the lookups are actually happening inside other shapes and the doStuff() isn't necessarily common functionality. Thanks though :)